# Getting error: "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr' failed:" next.js

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, next.js

My hot reload on next.js stopped working suddenly.

Tried:

- Restarting computer
- Restarting vs code
- uninstalling and reinstalling all modules

[image]

Comment: Hi, just wanted to have the update if you got the solution?